# Finding the longest consecutive sequence of integers that appears in both integers

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming

I am given two integers **X** and **Y**.  The goal is to find the **longest consecutive sequence** of  integers that appears in both X and Y.  So, if X = 124534891 and Y = 324534768, then the output would be **24534** since we have 1**24534**891 and 3**24534**768. The integers can be of different length.

I am trying to design a dynamic algorithm solution, but I'm completely lost.

Comment: Have you tried an approach with table of size len(X)*len(Y)?

Comment: `integers can be of different length` What *is* the *length of an integer*? MMXXI is longer than 2021? When & how does an *integer appear in an integer*? *Twenty* in *twenty-one*? Prime factors appear in integers, such as two and three in six.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of [Longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

Consider the numbers as strings and apply the same algorithm as for LCS problem.
Here's pseudocode to get started,

```
function maxConsecutiveSequence(A, B):
    S[N] = toString(A) 
    T[M] = toString(B)
    L = array(N, M)
    len = 0
    ans = {}

    for i = 1 to r
        for j = 1 to n
            if S[i] = T[j]
                if i = 1 or j = 1
                    L[i][j] = 1
                else
                    L[i][j] = L[i - 1][j - 1] + 1
                if L[i][j] > len
                    len = L[i][j]
                    ans = {S[i − z + 1..i]}
                else if L[i][j] = len
                    ans = ans ∪ {S[i − z + 1..i]}
            else
                L[i][j] = 0
    return ans
```